# How to factor $f''(x) = \frac{-12(x^2 + 3)^2 - (-48x(x^2 + 3)x)}{((x^2 + 3)^4))}$

Tags: calculus, factoring

$$ f''(x) = \frac{-12(x^2 + 3)^2 - (-48x(x^2 + 3)x)}{((x^2 + 3)^4))} $$

The result is

$$ f''(x) = \frac {36(x+1)(x-1)}{(x^2+3)^3} $$

My try

$$ f''(x) = \frac{-12x^2 - 36 - (-48x(x^2 + 3)x)}{((x^2 + 3)^3))} $$

Comment: Take out a factor of $x^2+3$ from numerator and denominator first. Then expand $-12(x^2+3)$ and collect like terms in the numerator. Finally, use $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$.

Comment: @Mattos thanks, I'll try

Comment: @dando18 I wasn't seeing a way to factor.

Comment: @Mattos I didn't understand how you used the $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$, see my edit pls.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

the numerator can be written as

$$12 (x^2+3)\Bigl (-(x^2+3)+4x^2\Bigr) $$